# How Insert more then 300000 Products in magento

Tags: magento, range, product

I need to insert more then 300000 products in magento.
I have already inserted 250000 products. But after that I do not know why I am not able to import any more .csv file. I can choose the file in magento import tool but it stops further working and shows me only loading image.
I need solution for this ASAP.

Looking for your answers.

Thank you.

Comment: There is very little information to go on here, but judging by the amount of information you're talking about I would imagine it's either timing out or running out of memory. I'd try chunking the file into several smaller files and run through them one at a time.

Comment: did you split the csv file? maybe value larger than accepted limit ( I mean PHP side )

Comment: I am importing the same size .csv. I have imported 80 .csv files so total products imported 250000+. but now I am not able to import the other .csv. I have also try to split large .csv file to few small .csv file and after that still can not import .csv files.

Comment: We wrote our own extension for this.  We currently have stores in the upwards of 4-5 million, but you could look into http://www.unirgy.com//products/urapidflow/ which I have heard good things about but if you are looking to do large amount of products you should look into a CLI importer and not something dependent on Magento Admin sessions and as Cags said you are probably reaching your memory_limit or your max_execution_time in PHP.

Comment: Possibly another thing to try would be [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/magmi/) which puts the products directly into the database

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Magento admin->System->Index Management
```

Select all and put the Index mode to manual.

**UPDATE 1**

```
Go to System->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings
```

the values should be:

```
Yes
system.log
exception.log
```

The save conf. Make sure that on ftp server the (mage root)/var/log is writable and there are 2 writeable files: system.log and exception.log

You can do them writable by: chmod 777 -R ./var in case u are in mage root.

After that start import again and when your system hangs, check the var/log directory .log files for any error.

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your help.
But this solution is not working for me. 
I follow your steps and then again try to import the .csv file and then systen still stop working and showing me loading image.